# How can i see if a socket is already connected to my server?

Tags: java, sockets, server, client, client-server

I'm writing a client/server app in java. Is this code correct to check if some socket of a client is already connected to my server? I'm quite new and it is my first app with this characteristics so don't kill me...

```
package ServerCommunication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class MultiServer {

    public void openSocket() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
        boolean listening = true;
        MultiServerThread w=null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1633);
            System.out.println("Waiting on 1633.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 1633.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        while (listening) {
            System.out.println("Hearing");
            Socket mysocket=serverSocket.accept();
            if(mysocket.isConnected())
                System.out.println("Already connected");
            else{
                System.out.println("Need to create one");
                w = new MultiServerThread(mysocket);
                Thread t = new Thread(w);
                t.start();
                    }
        }

        serverSocket.close();
        System.out.println("Multiserver closed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

```
while (listening) {
    System.out.println("Hearing");
    Socket mysocket=serverSocket.accept();
```

The result of executing this line of code is either an `IOException` or a `Socket` connected to the client.

```
    if(mysocket.isConnected())
```

Pointless. It's connected. Remove.

```
        System.out.println("Already connected");
```

Of course it's connected. That's what `accept()` is for. Remove.

```
        else{
```

Unreachable. Remove.

```
            System.out.println("Need to create one");
```

No you don't. Remove.

```
            w = new MultiServerThread(mysocket);
            Thread t = new Thread(w);
            t.start();
```

This is all pointless. Remove.